# How to read first 2 rows of csv from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, csv, google-cloud-storage

I need to read first 2 rows of csv file and store that in array to determine file_type,reportingdate and other metadata. My file is in Google cloud Storage.How can I read first 2 rows and store that in array in python script . I am trying with below code :

```
storage_client = storage.Client()

from google.cloud import storage
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('test_deepshikha')
blob = storage.Blob('intercompany_2rows_duplicates.csv', bucket)
content = blob.download_as_string()

for row in content:
    print (row)
```

It is printing the csv data but every character is being printed as string. I need row data in array. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the function name, I am assuming that the content variable is one very long string. If that is the case, then there ought to be newline characters in the string. You can simply split the string using newline as a delimiter and grab the first two values. Something like this:

```
lines = content.split('\n')[:2]
```

Comment: To be more clear. CSV's first row contains something like below :
"MTA|GLRS|GLOBAL|ALL|67_glrs_intercompany_override|2017-04-30|2017-05-01-03.03.55.123456||662|1.0 "
and Second row contains column headers:
HDR,source system,involved party id,involved party id type,intercompany id

I need to store these two rows for further processing.How can i store it in array within python code? help will be much appreciated

Comment: Your solution is working perfectly. Thanks for a brilliant solution. I have given-- lines = content.split('\n')[:1] and can store first row in array like ['MTA|GLRS|GLOBAL|ALL|67_glrs_intercompany_override|2017-04-30|2017-05-01-03.03.55.123456||661|1.0 \r'] . Trying to find how to store without \r

Comment: Hi David, I need another help on similar question, how can i loop through each row..I need to find duplicate values for Primary key fields. I can form a loop for each row but how can i just get nth row using above split ?

Comment: explain what you mean by row. Do you mean what is returned when you split the string on the newline? Are you calling that entire thing a row? If this is the so, then when you split the entire string you will get a list with each row as an item in the list. to get a particular item in the list, you can reference it by its position in the list. For example, to get the 3rd item in the list rows: rows[2]

Comment: Thanks David. Got it now and able to check duplicate rows successfully. Many thanks.