# How to read only first row of csv from Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have seen this question: [How to read first 2 rows of csv from Google Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46272702/how-to-read-first-2-rows-of-csv-from-google-cloud-storage)

But in my case, I don't want to load whole csv blob into memory, as it could be huge. Is there any way to open it as some iterable (or file-like object), and read only bytes of first couple of lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API for `google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob` specifies that the `download_as_string` method has `start` and `end` keywords that provide byte ranges:

> https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob

EDIT:
`download_as_string` is deprecated in favor of [download_as_byte](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.download_as_bytes)

Answer (score 6):

Wanted to expand answer of simzes with example of how to create iterable in cases where we do not know size of CSV header. Also could be useful for reading CSV from datastore line by line:

```
def get_csv_header(blob):
    for line in csv.reader(blob_lines(blob)):
        return line


# How much bytes of blob download using one request.
# Selected experimentally. If there is more optimal value for this - please update.
BLOB_CHUNK_SIZE = 2000


def blob_lines(blob: storage.blob.Blob) -> Generator[str, None, None]:
    position = 0
    buff = []
    while True:
        chunk = blob.download_as_string(start=position, end=position + BLOB_CHUNK_SIZE).decode()
        if '\n' in chunk:
            part1, part2 = chunk.split('\n', 1)
            buff.append(part1)
            yield ''.join(buff)
            parts = part2.split('\n')
            for part in parts[:-1]:
                yield part
            buff = [parts[-1]]
        else:
            buff.append(chunk)

        position += BLOB_CHUNK_SIZE + 1  # Blob chunk is downloaded using closed interval
        if len(chunk) < BLOB_CHUNK_SIZE:
            yield ''.join(buff)
            return
```

Answer (score 4):

if you have gsutil installed on your machine:

```
import subprocess
uri = 'gs://my-bucket/my-file.txt'
input_file_columns = subprocess.getoutput(f'gsutil cp {uri} - | head -1')
```

You can also use a tool called gcsfs (`pip install gcsfs`)

```
>>> import gcsfs
>>> fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='my-google-project')
>>> fs.ls('my-bucket')
['my-file.txt']
>>> fs.read_block('gs://my-bucket/my-file.txt', offset=1000, length=10, delimiter=b'\n')
b'A whole line of text\n'
```

GCSFS also has a `head` method.
https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/